# Prime divisors of the sequence terms $a_n=a\cdot 2017^n+b\cdot 2016^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math, prime-factorization

I am dealing with the test of the OBM (Brasilian Math Olimpyad), University level, 2017, phase 2.

As I've said at another topic (question 1), I hope someone can help me to discuss this test.

The question 2 says:

> Taking fixed positive integers $a$ and $b$, show that the set of the prime divisors of the sequence terms $a_n=a\cdot 2017^n+b\cdot 2016^n$ is infinite.

The only thing that is on my mind is Dirichlet's Theorem: ***Given any $k,k'\in\mathbb{Z}$ coprime, the arithmetic progression of reason k' and inicial term k has infinite primes.***

However, I don't have ideas about how do it. Thanks very much.

***Edit September, 01***

I was searching about recurrences and I found a little about Lucas sequences, it seems important:
[Lucas sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_sequence)

Comment: what is $\gcd(a_n, a_m) \; ? $ It is not necessary for any of the terms $a_n$ to be prime, so Dirichlet is not involved.

Comment: @WillJagy: The question asks for _infinitely many primes_ $p$ that each has the property that $p\mid a_n$ for infinitely many $n$. If we can find some nontrivial arithmetic progression such that every prime in the progression would have the property, then we can use Dirichlet.

Comment: @HenningMakholm interesting. In English the wording seems ambiguous to me... I am pretty sure the original was in Portugese. I like my version, but you may also have a point

Comment: @HenningMakholm the kind of thing I am thinking fits the Fermat numbers, where the union of the sets of prime divisors  is infinite because they are pairwise coprime...

Comment: @WillJagy: Hmm, rereading the problem, I think what I initially understood is probably a stronger statement than was actually asked for.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, yes, it was in Portuguese. Sorry for any wrongs words in the translate. Well, when you say "for infinitely many $n$" I believe that is "for at least one $n$"... right?

Comment: @Na'omi: Yes, that was what I ought to have said. Though, due to Fermat's little theorem, if $p\mid a_n$ for some $n\ge 1$, then we also have $p\mid a_{n+k(p-1)}$ for every $k\ge 0$, so the difference actually disappears (unless $p\mid a_0$, which is only the case for finitely many $p$).

Comment: @WillJagy: I'm not getting anywhere with your gcd hint. For example, for $a=2016$ and $b=2017$ I get $\gcd(a_0,a_1)=1$, but $\gcd(a_n,a_m)\ge 2016\cdot 2017$ for $1\le n<m$ ...

Comment: @HenningMakholm it might be something like the Fibonacci numbers, $F_m$ and $F_n$ are coprime if $m,n$ are coprime. https://proofwiki.org/wiki/GCD_of_Fibonacci_Numbers   This is more realistic than the Fermat number example, as we are looking at a degree two linear recurrence here.

Comment: @WillJagy: For clarity, do you have a concrete solution in mind, or are you just suggesting an approach you think _might_ be fruitful?

Comment: @HenningMakholm it might be fruitful. On the other hand, I just ran a test with $a=b=1.$ When $\gcd(m,n) = 1,$ (both up to 100) I found $\gcd(a_m, a_n) = 1, 4033.$ Either $1$ or $4033,$ no other gcd's come up

Comment: @HenningMakholm in any case, sorry if I wasted your time.

Comment: @WillJagy: Not at all. The observation that the $a_n$s satisfy a second-order recurrence is interesting.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, about the Fermat's little theorem, in fact!, thanks for answer and teach.

Comment: @WillJagy, about the degree two linear recurrence here, interesting observation. I've done the calculus and find $a_{n+1}=4033a_n-4066272a_{n-1}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose the set of primes dividing the sequence is finite instead, and number them $p_1,...,p_K.$

Associate to each term $a_n = a \cdot 2016^n + b \cdot 2017^n$ the index $i, 1 \le i \le K,$ such that biggest prime power that divides $a_n$ is  $p_i^{\beta_i(n)}$.

By the pigeonhole principle, there is an index $i_0$ and $a_n,a_m,\,m>n,m-n \le K,$ such that $a_n,a_m$ are both associated to $i_0,$ for each $n.$ Therefore, letting $l = \min(\beta_{i_0}(n),\beta_{i_0}(m)),$ we get that

$$ p_{i_0}^l | a\cdot 2016^n + b\cdot 2017^n, p_{i_0}^l | a \cdot 2016^m + b\cdot 2017^m.$$

The relations above imply, on the other hand, that

$$ p_{i_0}^l | b\cdot(2016^{m-n} - 2017^{m-n}). $$

From the fact that the number of primes is bounded, we get that $p_{i_0}^{l \cdot K} \ge 2017^n.$ On the other hand, by the equation above,

$$ p_{i_0}^l \le C \cdot 2017^K.$$

As $K$ is fixed, we see that

$$ 2017^{\frac{n}{K} - K} \le C, \text{for infinitely many } n \in \mathbb{N}.$$

This leads to a contradiction by letting $n \to \infty.$

Comment: Thanks very much for the great help, but I'm still trying understand how you could get $p_{i_0}^l | b\cdot(2016^{m-n} - 2017^{m-n})$, could you explain, please? Thanks again.

Comment: @Na'omi Of course! :D So, from the equations we have that $p_{i_0}^l | 2016^{m-n}(a \cdot 2016^n + b \cdot 2017^n) = a \cdot 2016^m + b \cdot 2016^{m-n} \cdot 2017^n.$ Subtracting the other relation, it yields $p_{i_0}^l | b \cdot 2016^{m-n} \cdot 2017^n - b \cdot 2017^m = 2017^n \cdot b \cdot (2016^{m-n} - 2017^{m-n}).$ By a similar method, we get also that $p_{i_0}^l | 2016^n \cdot a\cdot(2017^{m-n} - 2016^{m-n}).$ Finally, as $\text{gcd}(2016,2017) = 1,$ we get that either $p_{i_0}^l |  a\cdot(2017^{m-n} - 2016^{m-n})$ or $p_{i_0}^l |  b\cdot(2017^{m-n} - 2016^{m-n}).$

Comment: @Na'omi we just assume that in the above the second option happens to simplify things!

Comment: NOW I think I could understand, I thank you very much! This question was very difficult to me.

Comment: How do you know this $p_{i_0}^{l \cdot K} \ge 2017^n.$?